# What does one mean by "Ethical norm"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrases, phrase-meaning

I have been given a topic for writing an essay on ""Ethical norms with regard to Fundamental Rights "". I can't understand the meaning of this topic, please help.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. **Questions that can be answered using [commonly-available references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available) are off-topic**. Please make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: The right thing to do is to ask the person who set the topic. Or failing that, look in a dictionary or encyclopedia for the terms, and then ask here about what that research revealed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whereas the meaning of morals tends to reflect a standard of behavior we use with people we know, the definition of ethics tends to refer to the standards of behavior we apply in regard to strangers.  Therefore, the term ethical norms refers to behaviors we as a society expect from society at large.  While some ethics and morals do fall under the purview of law, most do not.  Where ethical standards do overlap with legal standards is where concern for fundamental rights comes into play with regard to ethical norms.

Based on this, your essay should be about what society expects of others in the way of behavior in relation to the freedoms government affords or should afford citizens.  A few recent examples in the US in which ethical norms have overlapped with fundamental rights include same-sex marriage, gun control, and marijuana use.  Societal expectations and ethical norms, with regard to each of these examples, evolved to not align with fundamental rights legally afforded.  These recent examples have resulted in both social and legal change, such as the Supreme Court recognizing same-sex marriages, a strong push by the Executive Branch towards limiting the Second Amendment that has been somewhat surprisingly met by a huge increase in gun sales among a large portion of the populous that indicates society may not be ready to sacrifice its fundamental rights in order to create increased legal enforcement of ethical concerns regarding guns, and the ongoing legalization of marijuana in many states.  These are just a few examples of how one might approach the subject of ethical norms with regard to fundamental rights.

Hopefully, with the above context, you are able to better understand what is meant by the term "ethical norm," what is meant by the term "fundamental right," and how they in turn relate to one another.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I cant understand this line meaning properly. Please help me with this line "Societal expectations, ethical norms, with regard to each of these examples evolved to not align with fundamental rights legally afforded."

Comment: I revised the sentence to make it easier to understand.